# Is there a way in Python to read one column in a CSV file and randomly select one value to put into a string variable?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have CSV file which has the following:
| Task 1   | Task 2         |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
I want to select a random value from Task 1 column and then write a string variable.

I have the following:

```py
    dict_from_csv = pd.read_csv('activities.csv', header=0, squeeze=True, index=False).to_dict()
    print(dict_from_csv)

    global after_work
    global before_bed
    after_work = random.choice(list(dict_from_csv.items()))
    before_bed = random.choice(list(dict_from_csv.values()))
```

But I'm not sure if using a dictionary is the right way of going about it.

Updated, thank you politinsa

I've had to change the code slightly to match what I have on the system, index parameter did not work so had to change it to index_col. I now receive the following errors:

```py
line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Evening'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bfree\PycharmProjects\Whattodo\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    before_bed = df['Evening'].iloc[np.random.randint(len(df))]
  File "C:\Users\bfree\PycharmProjects\Whattodo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\bfree\PycharmProjects\Whattodo\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Evening'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('activities.csv', header=0, squeeze=True, index=False)
after_work = df['Task 1'].iloc[np.random.randint(len(df))]
before_bed = df['Task 1'].iloc[np.random.randint(len(df))]
```